# iTunes 11 Mini Player disappeared off screen

Tags: itunes

I accidentally dragged the iTunes 11 Mini Player off screen (near the OS X menu bar) and it disappeared. Showing all windows on the screen didn't help, the player window is nowhere to be seen. Switching to the main iTunes Window works, but as soon as I switch to the Mini Player again, it's off screen again. How can I get it back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a couple of minutes of trying, I got the window back. Since I couldn't find this solution on Google, I'm answering it here for other people if they run into the same issue.

To get the Mini Player window back if it's off screen, use the iTunes `View > Show Up Next` menu entry. In my case, it moved the Mini Player window to a location right beneath the OS X menu bar and displayed the `Up Next` list, allowing me to move the Mini Player to a location of my choice.